# Using C++ to find Coordinates of Flash Object

Tags: c++, flash, automation

I want to figure out how to use C++ to find the coordinates of a flash object.

I intend to create an automation based on the coordinates of the object, and I need to coordinates to make sure that the automation will run across different screen resolutions and window placements.

To accomplish this I just need to get one part of the object's coordinates, ie. the top left corner or something. Then I would base all other actions off of the original coordinates of the flash object.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are we talking about a Flash Object that is running in the browser or in the local flash player?

Comment: This is a Flash Object running in the browser